# no me esta actualizando 2 registros problemas en el controlador

Tags: laravel, oracle

El problema que tengo es con id_enlace y periodo no me esta actualizando esos 2 registros no se por que ya intente quitarlos y si me funciona todo correcto no se si es por que son los que utilizo para identificar el unico registro pero no me actualiza esos 2 registos

este es mi formulario

```
  <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="content">
                        @foreach($info as $info)

                            {{ Form::open(array('route' => ['editar_datos_post',$info->id_enlace,$info->periodo])) }}
                                @csrf
                                @method('POST')

                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <label for="inputEmail4">Proveedor</label>
                                        {{Form::text('proveedor',$info->proveedor,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Desc_enlace</label>
                                    {{Form::text('desc_enlace',$info->desc_enlace,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="inputEmail4">Id_enlace</label>
                                        {{Form::text('id_enlace',$info->id_enlace,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="inputPassword4">Valor_pago</label>
                                        {{Form::text('valor_pago',$info->valor_pago,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="inputEmail4">Periodo</label>
                                        {{Form::text('periodo',$info->periodo,['class'=>'form-control'])}}

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                        {{Form::submit('Actualizar',['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}
                        @endforeach
                            {{ Form::close() }}
                    </div>
```

esta es mi ruta

```
Route::POST('editar_datos_post/{id_enlace}/{periodo}',[
    'as'=>'editar_datos_post',
    'uses'=>'editar_datos@editar_post'
]);
```

este es mi controlador en el cual quiero actualizar los registros pero no me esta actualizando y solo me actualiza proveedor,desc_enlace,valor_pago 
y los 2 registros que quiero que me actualice no me los esta actualizando no se por que

```
 public function editar_post(Request $request)
    {
        \DB::beginTransaction();
        $date =  strtotime($request->periodo);
        $dat= date("Ymd H:i:s", $date);
        $moneda='D';
        $tc_factura=25;
        $proveedor= $request->proveedor;
        $no_factura=$proveedor.'_PROFORMA';


        try {
            importar::where('id_enlace','=',$request->id_enlace)->where('periodo','=',$request->periodo)->update([
                'PROVEEDOR' => $request->proveedor,
                'DESC_ENLACE' => $request->desc_enlace,
                "NO_FACTURA" => $no_factura,
                'ID_ENLACE' => $request->id_enlace,
                'VALOR_PAGO' => $request->valor_pago,
                'PERIODO' =>$dat,
                'MONEDA' => $moneda,
                'TC_FACTURA' => $tc_factura,
            ]);
            \DB::commit();
            return back()->with('messagee', 'exito');;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \DB::rollback();
            return back()->with('messagee', 'Problemas');
        }
    }
```

esta es mi tabla y solo id_enlace y periodo no me los actualiza

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Verificaste el tipo de dato sea correcto en la BD, es decir que si es un entero en la BD no estes ingresando un string

Comment: El $id_enlace =number y el $periodo=date  no se si ese es el problema

Comment: ahi coloque en mi respuesta mis campos de mi tabla